# Image Button background not transparent ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I am trying from one hour to add an image as button in ionic , the image is png with transparent background but failed it always show a white background my code is:

```
<p align="center"><button (click)="buttonTapped()">
<ion-img style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background: transparent 
!important;" src="img/btn1.png"></ion-img>  </button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `<button>`-element and place the `(click)`-handler on the `<ion-img>`-tag directly. Also to set background color use `background-color` not `background`

Your code would look something like this:

```
<p align="center"><ion-img (click)="buttonTapped()"style="width: 150px; 
height: 150px; background: transparent !important;" src="img/btn1.png">
</ion-img>
```